# What are some hot peppers that ripen black on the last stage?

Tags: plant-recommendations, peppers, chili

I'm looking for chili pepper recommendations: what are some chili peppers that ripen to black on the last stage of ripening? I know plenty that start green, turn black and then turn red, but I want ones that stay black once they turn black.

Okay, so if you don't know any that ripen to black at last, ones that are purple or brown at the last stage will also work. I think maybe the chocolate habanero stays brown when fully ripe, but I'm not 100% sure on that. I've heard that 'Purple Beauty' turns purplish red on the last stage, but it's a sweet pepper.

Answer (score 2):

To start the list of black, deep reddish black and dark brown:

Poblano/Ancho, Chipotle Morita, Passilla, Guajarillo, Czech Black, Sweet Chocolate, Cascabel

Others that can have black mottling:

Mojo

Chipotle Morita is a very dark waxy red Jalapeno that turns black when lightly smoked.